# Does ARM frsqrts need to be used with extra fmul instructions for a Newton iteration?

Tags: assembly, arm, newtons-method, sqrt, square-root

In the documentation for the ARM instruction [frsqrts](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/h/A64-SIMD-Scalar-Instructions/FRSQRTS--scalar-), it says:

> This instruction multiplies corresponding floating-point values in the vectors of the two source SIMD and FP registers, subtracts each of the products from 3.0, divides these results by 2.0, places the results into a vector, and writes the vector to the destination SIMD and FP register.

I interpret this as yₙ₊₁ = (3 - xyₙ)/2-and indeed the following code justifies this interpretation:

```
.global _main
.align 2
_main:
    fmov d0, #2.0 // Goal: Compute 1/sqrt(2)
    fmov d1, #0.5 // initial guess
    frsqrts d2, d0, d1 // first approx

    mov x0, 0
    mov x16, #1 // '1' = terminate syscall
    svc #0x80   // "supervisor call"
```

However, reading about the [Newton iterate for the inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root), I see that the iteration is *not* yₙ₊₁ = (3 - xyₙ)/2, but rather yₙ₊₁ = yₙ(3 - xyₙ²)/2. Now, obviously I can use `frsqrt` in combination with other instructions to get this:

```
    fmov d0, #2.0 // Goal: Compute 1/sqrt(2)
    fmov d1, #0.5 // initial guess
    fmul d2, d1, d1 // initial guess squared
    frsqrts d3, d0, d2 // (3-r*r*x)/2
    fmul d4, d1, d3 // d4 = r*(3-r*r*x)/2
```

But is seems weird to introduce a custom instruction which only get your halfway to your goal. Am I misusing this instruction?

Comment: You'd think they might have an application note with sample code, but I couldn't find one either.

Comment: "But it seems weird to introduce a custom instruction which only get your halfway to your goal."  But remember, this is a RISC machine.  It's reasonable to have a custom instruction here because it's just a glorified fused multiply-subtract, which the machine already has dedicated hardware for (e.g. for `fmsub`.  The only difference is that one operand is hardcoded as 3 to save you a register, and the bonus feature of dividing by two at the end.  The latter just means decrementing the exponent, and there's hardware for that too, for instructions like `shadd`.

Comment: By contrast, there's presumably no special hardware to fuse *two* multiplications, so if there was an instruction to do the whole thing, it would just have to be microcoded, and wouldn't be any faster than doing the first multiply as a separate instruction.  All you'd gain is code density, and it isn't the RISC way to achieve that through microcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This represents an entirely conventional partitioning of the Newton-Raphson iteration for the reciprocal square root into simple RISC-like instructions.

For example, in AMD's 3dNow! instruction set extension for x86, this is the functionality of the instruction `PFRSQIT1` (full disclosure: this is something I designed <sup>[1]</sup>). This functionality does not even require underlying FMA capability: It can be implemented via a slight modification to an existing multiplier since the result is close to 1.0 when it is used as intended, that is, as part of the NR-iteration for the reciprocal square root.

As the asker deduced, `frsqrts` needs to receive the *square* of the current estimate for the reciprocal square root as one of its source operands. Since the `frsqrte` instruction delivers an estimate to 1/sqrt(x) accurate to about 8 bits, computing a single-precision reciprocal square root will require two Newton-Raphson iterations. Conceptually:

```
     frsqrte  est0, x             // initial approximation, accurate to about 8 bits

     fmul     est0_sq, est0, est0 // first NR iteration for reciprocal square root
     frsqrts  tmp, est0_sq, x
     fmul     est1, tmp, est0     

     fmul     est1_sq, est1, est1 // second NR iteration for reciprocal square root
     frsqrts  tmp, est1_sq, x
     fmul     res, tmp, est1
```

This instruction sequence maps directly to a sequence of corresponding intrinsics: `vrsqrte_f32()`, `vmul_f32()`, and `vrsqrts_f32()`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> S. Oberman, F. Weber, N. Juffa, and G. Favor, "AMD 3DNow!<sup>TM</sup> Technology and the K6-2 Microprocessor." In *HotChips 10*, August 16-18, 1998 ([online](https://old.hotchips.org/wp-content/uploads/hc_archives/hc10/3_Tue/HC10.S10/HC10.10.3.pdf))